# Is it possible to import system.storage running Jag v1.7.1

Tags: toit

I am wanting to persist values on my ESP32 devices running Jaguar.

```
$ jag version
Version:     v1.7.1
SDK version:     v2.0.0-alpha.33
Build date:  2022-10-15T18:12:13Z
```

The best I could find was this in the documentation: https://libs.toit.io/system/storage/class-Bucket.

However, when I try to run a program with the import statement:

```
import system.storage
```

I get the following traceback:

```
$ jag run main.toit
Running 'main.toit' on 'mqtt' ...
main.toit:1:1: error: Failed to find import 'system.storage'
import system.storage
^~~~~~
main.toit:1:15: note: Missing library file. Tried '<sdk>/system/storage.toit' and '<sdk>/system/storage/storage.toit'
import system.storage
              ^~~~~~~
Compilation failed.
```

Is this a Toit only library and not compatible with Jaguar? If it does work with Jaguar, am I using the wrong version, or do I need to install some additional package?

Or are Buckets even the right way to do this? I just need to persist simple values is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaguar 1.7.1 is too old for the `storage` library. The current release of Jaguar (as of August 2023) is v1.10.0, which is roughly 10 months more recent.

The storage library was added with SDK v2.0.0-alpha.53, but v1.7.1 only ships with alpha-33. The current SDK release is alpha-90.

Buckets are the correct way to persist data on the device.